# PHP includes/require in a file and all functions inside it

Tags: php

I have a file which I include say:

```
    require_once("../../constructor/database.php");

$stuff_inside_include_file->doThis() ; //ACCESSIBLE

function createUser(){
   $stuff_inside_include_file->doThat(); //NOT-ACCESSIBLE (object not found)
} 

function deleteUser(){
. ...
```

If I move the require statement into the scope of the function, then it works. Otherwise, it doesn't. Is there a better solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: add some more code $stuff_inside_include_file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
function createUser($stuff_inside_include_file){
   $stuff_inside_include_file->doThat();
}
```

it should work, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to not create global variables, but this would also work:

```
require_once("../../constructor/database.php");

$stuff_inside_include_file->doThis() ; //ACCESSIBLE

function createUser(){
    global $stuff_inside_include_file;
    $stuff_inside_include_file->doThat(); //ACCESSIBLE
} 

function deleteUser(){
. ...
```

But really.. "Think globally, act in local scope".

Comment: @tereško: learn to read; i explicitly suggested he _should_not_ use globals. twice.

Comment: but you showed only how to use globals .. do you really think the OP will put an effort in looking for alternatives ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an issue with the variable not being global.

e.g.

```
$i = 10;

function pooppoop() {

    $i = 11;
    #this only sets the local variable i to 11

}
```

So you will want to put a global $i; at the top of your function. Obviously replace $i with the variable you are having trouble accessing.

Answer (score -1):

I looks like the $stuff_inside_include_file variable is in the global scope, so you should be able to do this:

```
function createUser(){
   global $stuff_inside_include_file;
   $stuff_inside_include_file->doThat();
}
```

Comment: I'm not suggesting it, I'm answering his question.  The variable is in the global scope, and that is how you access it from inside the function.  Global variable usage is a different issue.

Comment: no, the answer would have been passing the variable to function

Comment: @teresko What's the downside of using global?

Comment: @stackplasm http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil and http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad should clear it up